# Align DIV Tags Horizontally

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have some div tags which I am using as contact links on my website. They are meant to be located on the right hand side and be aligned in one line.

Currently looks like:

[image: Current alignment]

Preferred alignment:

[image: Preferred alignment]

Code below:

```css
#book-me {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      z-index: 99999;
      top: 50%;
      background: black;
      color:white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #book-me a {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: sofia-pro;
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      #book-me {
        bottom: 0;
        top: initial;
        transform: none;
      }
      #book-me a {
        writing-mode: initial;
        padding: 5px 10px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="book-me">
  <a href="tel:############">Call</a>,
  <a href="sms:############">Text</a> or
  <a href="############">WhatsApp</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be better off using `transform: rotate` instead of `writing-mode: vertical-rl` if it is just a visualization preference and not intended to be used for vertical-oriented languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just rotate your book-me div (use full screen on snippet below to see transform):

```css
#book-me {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  z-index: 99999;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#book-me a {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sofia-pro;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #book-me {
    transform: none;
  }
  #book-me a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="book-me">
  <a href="tel:############">Call</a>,
  <a href="sms:############">Text</a> or
  <a href="############">WhatsApp</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` tags are only used to apply links to text, so they do not format the text on a block-level in any way. Format them as divs to get the effect you want. Note that this code does not contain anything to rotate the text 90 degrees as I assume based on your screenshots you already wrote that elsewhere.

```css
#book-me {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      z-index: 99999;
      top: 50%;
      background: black;
      color:white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #book-me a {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: sofia-pro;
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      #book-me {
        bottom: 0;
        top: initial;
        transform: none;
      }
      #book-me a {
        writing-mode: initial;
        padding: 5px 10px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="book-me">
  <div><a href="tel:############">Call</a></div>,
  <div><a href="sms:############">Text</a></div> 
  <div>or</div>
  <div><a href="############">WhatsApp</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the rotation is being handled by the `writing-mode: vertical-rl` CSS property. I believe it's purpose is more for vertical languages like Japanese Kanji or something, but it also rotates strings of latin characters 90 degrees.

Comment: @webdevkit Huh, TIL, thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply. I have added each link inside a div tag and it works now. One snag is that on mobile it now stacks them vertically rather than horizontally although I am not overly concerned with that.

Comment: @emvy03 You can ensure div display across different browsers by using flex or for something like this, css grid.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Code you were probably trying to achieve but to be honest this is less than ideal and I would recommend just rotate your box since your approach isn't meant to be used like that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#book-me {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}

#book-me span {
  transform: translateY(calc(50vh - 50%));
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

#book-me a {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sofia-pro;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #book-me {
    bottom: 0;
    top: initial;
    transform: none;
  }

  #book-me a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
}

p {
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="book-me">
  <span>
    <a href="tel:############">Call</a>,
    <a href="sms:############">Text</a> or
    <a href="############">WhatsApp</a>
  </span>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, doloremque!</p>
<p>Expedita fugit dolor amet ipsa voluptatibus, nesciunt eos beatae voluptas.</p>
<p>Vitae sapiente, nihil ea quam, asperiores error aliquam? Mollitia, nobis?</p>
<p>Veniam suscipit explicabo ipsum nobis hic sunt, ea laboriosam obcaecati!</p>
<p>Sunt explicabo consectetur eius ipsam maiores laborum inventore excepturi temporibus?</p>
<p>Blanditiis nulla tenetur, cum, placeat fuga sint sed itaque debitis.</p>
<p>Fugit nobis fuga sit, repellat quae doloremque, dolorum obcaecati suscipit!</p>
<p>Voluptas officiis veritatis excepturi possimus modi eum corporis, ducimus earum!</p>
<p>Dolorem expedita quae, numquam consequatur maiores veniam iure? Minus, quia?</p>
<p>Deserunt fugiat odit repellat impedit perferendis, minus minima. Facere, quidem.</p>
```